# RxJs only take the first value of certain type and skip the rest until a different type of value

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a scenario where I want to take only the first value of a certain type and then take the next different value which is of a different type.

To understand let's consider the following:

```
of(1,1,1,1,2,3,4)
.pipe(
    // some operators
)
.subscribe(val => console.log(val);
```

I am only interested in the output `1,2,3,4`

note that the 1 in the output should be the first value in the source and not the one before 2.

how do I achieve this using `rxjs` operators?

Comment: You would have to add logic to your pipe to ignore message values that match the previous value.

Comment: I can track the previous value outside and do a check to ignore the value but I was wondering if this is possible with just using the operators

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinct  possibly distinct, or distinctUntilChanged.  There are other options in the docs there.

Comment: Excellent, now I feel dumb for not noticing that good ol distinct can solve this. you can write the answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The operator you're looking for is called `distinctUntilChanged()`, like so:

```
of(1,1,1,1,2,3,4).pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This would result in 1, 2, 3, 4. Do note that any other value that has previously occured, will occur again, so it's not like a `DISTINCT` in SQL (e.g. 1,1,2,3,4,1 would produce output 1, 2, 3, 4, 1).

Comment: There is also [`distinct()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinct) operator as mentioned by @Taplar above, which does exclude all previously emitted values.

Answer (score 0):

So given 111223111

If you want to get 123 use distinct operator

If you want to get 1231 use distinctUntilChanged operator